# htaccess - 301 redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jlcustompc.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.jlcustompc.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jlcustompc.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.jlcustompc.net$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.jlcustompc.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RedirectMatch 301 /contactform.php /buymypc.php

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=http [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]
```

I want jlcustompc.net to redirect to https://www.jlcustompc.com

That is the only issue I am having. Also if there is anything else you see that could be added or replaced or modified let me know.

Here are the virtual host I have set just now and does not seem to work as intended.

The very first host I know works without a doubt.

```
<VirtualHost MYIP:443>
            ServerAdmin admin@jlcustompc.com
            DocumentRoot "ROOT"
            ServerName www.jlcustompc.com
            ErrorLog ERRORLOG
            SSLEngine on
            SSLProtocol all
            SSLCertificateFile "PATH"
            SSLCertificateKeyFile "PATH"
            SSLCACertificateFile "PATH"
            ServerPath "PATH"
            <Directory "PATH">
            </Directory>
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost MYIP:443>
            ServerAdmin admin@jlcustompc.com
            DocumentRoot "PATH"
            ServerName www.jlcustompc.net
            ErrorLog ERRORLOG
            SSLEngine on
            SSLProtocol all
            SSLCertificateFile "PATH"
            SSLCertificateKeyFile "PATH"
            SSLCACertificateFile "PATH"
            ServerPath "PATH"
            <Directory "PATH">
            </Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost MYIP:80>
            ServerAdmin admin@jlcustompc.com
            DocumentRoot "PATH"
            ServerName www.jlcustompc.net
            ErrorLog ERRORLOG
            ServerPath "PATH"
            <Directory "PATH">
            </Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost MYIP:80>
            ServerAdmin admin@jlcustompc.com
            DocumentRoot "PATH"
            ServerName www.jlcustompc.com
            ErrorLog ERRORLOG
            ServerPath "PATH"
            <Directory "PATH">
            </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What's the issue? Those rules look fine.

Comment: jlcustompc.net does not redirect at all but www.jlcustompc.net does ---- when I check the redirect for www.jlcustompc.net i get an error does not exist using a redirect tool. Not only that but i want jlcustompc.net/*.* to redirect to https://www.jlcustompc.com ---- basically anything .net needs to redirect to my home page of .com

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing all of this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jlcustompc.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.jlcustompc.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jlcustompc.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.jlcustompc.net$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.jlcustompc.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

with simply:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.jlcustompc.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.jlcustompc.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

EDIT:

> I added virtual host setting to httpd.....Let me put them in the main topic and you can take a look.

This is just a guess, but you don't seem to have any of the vhosts setup to handle `jlcustompc.net`, only `www.jlcustompc.net`. Under the `www.jlcustompc.net` vhosts, you should add:

```
ServerAlias jlcustompc.net
```

But it doesn't look like you have anything handling `jlcustompc.com` either but that seems to work.

Comment: @LisaLowery something else is wrong then, those rules in a blank htaccess file on a vanilla apache install work exactly as intended. 3 different requests for `jlcustompc.net`, `www.jlcustompc.net` and `jlcustompc.com` all redirect to `www.jlcustompc.com` http://i.stack.imgur.com/k0tpK.png

Comment: @LisaLowery your original rules work just fine for me as well

Comment: I want jlcustompc.net to redirect to HTTPS : // www .jlcustompc. com or really anything .net to redirect to my .com home page

Comment: @LisaLowery Like I said, working like intended: http://i.stack.imgur.com/W3omt.png

Comment: I see that in your picture. problem is when I type jlcustompc.net in my browser I get nothing......it works www.jlcustompc.net that redirects to www.jlcustompc.com ---- I prefer it to got to https: --- I do not know.....is it because I am actually on the server?

Comment: @LisaLowery Are you sure you've configured apache's virtualhost settings to point those *.net domains to the same place as the *.com domains? DNS doesn't resolve for any of the *.net domains. The rules are not the problem.

Comment: AHHHH ---- Ok lets try that again! I was using dyndns to manage the .net domain and I just got a static ip address. I added virtual host setting to httpd.....Let me put them in the main topic and you can take a look.

Comment: @LisaLowery I've edited my answer but at this point it's probably something more suitable for serverfault.com. This isn't about redirect rules or htaccess files.

Comment: I mostly got this working using webhops in my DNS settings. So all seems well for now THANKS!! You guys are great. I have it to a point now where it functions Thank you! Just having someone to bounce stuff off of is a great help!

Comment: @LisaLowery I'm just a regular user like you, everyone on the site is. Nobody here gets paid for consulting, they rely on [upvotes for useful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) and [accepting correct answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).